# How to make textbox appear when certain buttons are pressed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

All I want is a hidden textbox on a PHP page, and once a user pressed "CTRL + SHIFT + E" it will make the textbox visible. How do I even go about this? I had a look through a few like this:

```
$("input").keydown(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

But I don't see anywhere you can tell it what key is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback for the `keydown` listeners is passed a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), I suggest you read about them.

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'E'){
        $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"></input>
```

---

To modify this to make a text box visible, you should modify the `<input>`'s `display` css:

```js
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'E') {
    $("input").css("display", "inline-block");
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLowerCase()` to check for key `e` to make it work even when `capslock` is on:

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key.toLowerCase() == 'e'){
      $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text />
```